# Powershell, Posh-SSH Module: How is reading the stream supposed to work in Posh-SSH?

Tags: powershell-5.0

I'm trying to understand how reading a stream is supposed to work in Posh-SSH so I can put together a "wait-action" function so the script will continue only after the remote command has completed.

The intent of the code shown below, when put together, is to kick off a "yum update" on the remote system (Linux, CentOS 7), then monitor the stream to determine when the remote command has completed, then proceed to the next line of the script.  It does work "sometimes", but not consistently.

This code successfully sets up a new SSH Connection and defines a stream:

```
$hostIP = "Remote_Linux_Server_IP"
$centosCreds = "My_Credential_Object"
$pemFile = "My_Pem_File"
New-SSHSession -ComputerName $hostIP -Port 22 -Credential $centosCreds -KeyFile $pemFile -ConnectionTimeout 120 -OperationTimeout 120 -AcceptKey
$stream = New-SSHShellStream -Index 0
```

Executing a remote command through the new stream is easy enough:

```
Invoke-SSHStreamShellCommand -ShellStream $stream -Command "yum update"
```

Running the following while the Invoke-SSHStreamShellCommand command (yum update) is running returns a snippet of the remote command output as expected:

```
$stream.Read()
```

However, once the "yum update" is complete, the stream read returns only a blank value.  The information I've been able to find online indicates that the stream read should return the remote system command prompt string, but this does not appear to be the case.

Because the value returned by the read after the command has completed is blank, the "wait-action" loop I'm trying to put together doesn't work consistently:

```
$promptString = "Remote_System_Command_Prompt_String"
$streamOut = $stream.Read()
while ($streamOut -notlike "*$promptString*") {
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $streamOut = $stream.Read()
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here - documentation is limited and I haven't been able to find many other examples of Posh-SSH stream reading that match the behavior I'm seeing.

Any guidance or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the remote system's shell prompt normally look like? Does it match the -PromptPattern? _(Also, I'd say this approach of running commands by "driving" an interactive shell is a bit misguided to begin with; it does the job when there's absolutely no alternative, but normally you'd run each command in batch mode, e.g. by using Invoke-SSHCommandStream...)_

Comment: Thanks for the response Grawity - to answer your question, yes the shell prompt on the remote system does match the promptString variable.  I've updated the code example above to include the wildcards I use in my script.

Comment: Also, I tried using Invoke-SSHCommandStream, but it looks like it exhibits the same "problem" when executing a series of commands and would require a wait-action function to allow command #1 to complete before command #2 is sent to the remote host.  Any suggestions on how to manage the rate that commands are sent to the remote host (other than "Start-Sleep") would be welcome. @grawity

Answer (score 0):

This post is super old but was never answered really. I have never seen stream.reaed() return a command prompt. Some variation of this should probably work:

```
$promptString = "Remote_System_Command_Prompt_String"
$streamOut = $stream.Read()
while (($streamOut).length -ne 0) {
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $streamOut = $stream.Read()
}
```

other options would be to use -match and look for the phrase it uses when complete or sleeping longer and then checking the yum log for verification that it updated. Any of these would probably accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

`$stream.Read()` produces a single string with `/r/n` line breaks.

I had to put `$stream.Read()` into a variable and split it into an array. Then scan each line.

Long story short, wrote a [set of functions](https://github.com/GordonVi/SSH_Expect) to do this. Still testing it out.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199371)